# Checking if a timeslot/booking is taken

Tags: sql, logic

EDIT: The query Gordon posted appears to have a problem. If I have a booking from 10-12 it seems to consider all bookings past 12 pm invalid, but all bookings before 10am valid.

Some quick and simple thinking ended up in me creating the following query:

```
SELECT serverip 
        FROM   server 
        WHERE  serverip NOT IN (SELECT serverip 
                                FROM   booking 
                                WHERE  startat >= datehere 
                                AND expiresat <= datehere) 
        LIMIT  1;
```

Suppose the booking table stores the following:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| bookingid | serverip  | username | startat  | expiresat |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|         1 | 127.0.0.1 | testuser | 10:00    | 12:00     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

If the user was to input the following data for a booking:

```
startat = 9:59
expiresat = 12:01
```

They could easily bypass my check to see if the booking time is available based on previous bookings stored.

Any advice on how I could better solve this problem?

I would prefer **NOT** to limit the users input and would like to avoid hard coding specific time slots, if that wasn't a problem however I would stick with what I've got.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what db platform are you on? (oracle/sql server/mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM server
WHERE serverip NOT IN
(SELECT serverip 
 FROM booking
 WHERE
   (startat <= '2013-01-30 08:00:00' AND expiresat >= '2013-01-30 08:00:00') OR
   (startat <= '2013-01-30 09:00:00' AND expiresat >= '2013-01-30 09:00:00') OR
   (startat >= '2013-01-30 08:00:00' AND expiresat <= '2013-01-30 09:00:00'))
```

Where 8:00 is start time and 9:00 is expire.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the logic for the overlap.  Try this:

```
SELECT serverip 
FROM  server 
WHERE serverip NOT IN (SELECT serverip 
                       FROM booking 
                       WHERE startat <= USEREXPIREDATE AND
                             expiresat >= USERSTARTDATE
                      ) 
LIMIT  1;
```

A slot is occupied when it starts before the desired user expire date and ends after the desired user start date.

Comment: The same problem is present here. The above SQL query returned a serverip from the server table. The booking time 9:59 - 12:01 overlaps with 10-12, and should be considered an invalid booking. I used the same data as I provided in the original post.

Comment: @anditpainsme . . . Are you putting in the right values for USEREXPIREDDATE and USERSTARTDATE?  These are the two distinct values input by the user.

Comment: Oh right, a silly oversight. I actually didn't put the correct values. It appears this does actually work as I was hoping. I will do some further testing and write back. Thanks alot, anditpainsme

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution Gordon, simple but effective thinking.

Comment: If I have a booking from 10-12 the query you have provided seems to consider all bookings past 12 pm invalid, but all bookings before 10am valid

Answer (score 0):

There are four possibilities for time [as this pic says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UCeR.png)  and the code for what represent in the picture is

```
SELECT Id FROM reservations 
WHERE 
((start_at < @start_at AND start_at < @end_at) AND (end_at > @start_at AND end_at < @end_at))
OR((start_at > @start_at AND start_at < @end_at) AND (end_at > @start_at AND end_at > @end_at))
OR((start_at <= @start_at AND start_at <= @end_at) AND (end_at >= @start_at AND end_at >= @end_at))
OR((start_at >= @start_at AND start_at <= @end_at) AND (end_at >= @start_at AND end_at <= @end_at))
```